# How to build instances after extracting a CSV file containing multiples values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, extract

I am trying to make multiples instance of the class Employee from a CSV file that contains employees and extracted from a static method. From now I just can get a list of those employees but what I want is Instantly assign those values to an instance variable.

Here is my code:

class Employees():

```
nums_of_employees = 0

def __init__(self, name, last, salary):

    self.name = name
    self.last = last
    self.salary = salary
    Employees.nums_of_employees +=1

def data(self):
    print(f'Name: {self.name} LastName: {self.last} Salary: {self.salary}')

@staticmethod
def extract_csv():
    new_emp = []
    with open('Employees.csv', 'r') as data_file:
        csv_data = csv.DictReader(data_file)
        next(csv_data)

        for line in csv_data:
            new_emp += line['Name'], line['Last'], line['Salary']

        return new_emp
```

Comment: And where is your `Employee` class?

Comment: I just edited it, check now.

Comment: In that case, Optixal's answer should suffice, just use `Employees` instead of `Employee`.

Comment: // , Would you please show what you've tried or researched so far, before asking or in the mean time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Employee takes in 3 arguments (name, last and salary), you can replace

```
new_emp += (line['Name'], line['Last'], line['Salary'])
```

with

```
new_emp.append(Employee(line['Name'], line['Last'], line['Salary']))
```

to create a new Employee instance for every line you iterate through and append it to the `new_emp` list.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) to extract row wise data.

This is example in the official documentation of the link above

Generate an example Series

```
>>> s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(50))
>>> s.head()
0   -0.038497
1    1.820773
2   -0.972766
3   -1.598270
4   -1.095526
```

Extraction of 3 random elements from the Series:

```
>>> s.sample(n=3)
27   -0.994689
55   -1.049016
67   -0.224565
dtype: float64
```

You can also use this on DataFrame of pandas, to extract elements in the entire row.